# Custom defined javadoc for IntelliJ overridden method

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-generation

Is there a way to tell IntelliJ to generate such a javadoc

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
```

instead of copying the Javadoc from the parent method?

I've checked all options in `Settings -> Editor -> File and Code Templates` and the only one which was close was `Overridden Method Body` -- but I'm not sure how to use that to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible. Vote for this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-128817